# What is the distribution called where an area has a certain chance of being filled?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we divide an area into small squares and give each square a probability of being filled by an object. We get a random distribution of object.

In the limit where the squares go to zero.

What is the name of this distribution?

Comment: You have to have more conditions on the probability, as the squares shrink. Given such a limit exists, this is simply an arbitrary probability distribution.

Answer (score 0):

One might call such a distribution a **spatial distribution**, as it assigns a probability density to a geometric object.  But there are of course uncountably many such distributions.